# Avoid packing .jar into Android Library (.aar)

Tags: android, jar, gradle, android-studio, dropbox

My project is an Android Library which depends on Dropbox's android library.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    provided fileTree(dir: '../Libraries/Dropbox', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

Everything works well excepts Gradle puts all the .jar files from Dropbox into my output .aar file.

```
MyLib.aar
|-classes.jar
|-AndroidManifest.xml
|-...
|-libs
    |-bcprov-jdk16-146.jar
    |-commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
    |-dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1
    |-json_simple-1.1.jar
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Did none of the answers solve your problem? Please consider accepting one of them as the answer if they helped you. Or clarify why they did not help.

Answer (score 2):

something like this might help you:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def packageLib = output.getPackageLibrary()
        packageLib.exclude('libs/externalLibrary.jar')
    }
}
```

inside android {} block

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you want to avoid this? When you give your library to someone, they have all the dependencies already in one file.
2. You can include the dependencies via

> ```
> compile 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:1.7.7' 
> compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
> compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
> compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
> ```

in your build.gradle file and remove it from the libs folder. Do the same with the other dependencies. This way they will not be packaged into your .aar file.

Comment: Can I interpret your answer this way: 1. .aar library file will automatically include .jar file dependency. 2. .aar library file will **not** include gradle dependencies, client using .aar file must also add the same gradle dependencies manually?

Comment: Gradle dependencies are transitive. So if you depend on a certain library which in turn depends on others they will pulled in automatically.