# Avoid packaging jar dependencies into aar

Tags: android, gradle, jar, aar

I'm developing an android library for work and we're using some jars that are not available in maven repositories. However, we are not legally allowed to package these jars into our library, the consumer must get those jars themselves in addition to our library.

My problem is that I can't seem to require the consumer of our library to provide these jars (I'm using a test app that includes the aar). I tried the solutions for [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26908072/4571656) to no avail.

I have tried setting them to `provided` instead of `compile` in my gradle file:

```
// Neither of these seem to fix the problem
compile files('libs/externalDep.jar')
provided files('libs/externalDep.jar')
```

I also tried excluding them in packaging options:

```
packagingOptions { exclude 'libs/externalDep.jar }`
```

I can exclude them by adding this to the `android` tag in my `build.gradle`:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
variant.outputs.each { output ->
    def packageLib = output.getPackageLibrary()
    packageLib.exclude('libs/externalDep.jar')
}
```

They're not added to the aar but building the test app gives me:

```
com.android.build.api.transformTransformException:
  com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException:
    Duplicate files copied in APK VERSION.txt
File1: path/to/jar/in/test/app/project/externalDep.jar
File2: path/to/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/.../jars/classes.jar
```

To clarify, I'm not concerned at all with maven repo dependencies, those are working fine. I just want whoever uses the library to have to get and add those jars we're using too.
Surely there's a less convoluted way to specify this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The jar file must be moved up one level, from `mymodule/libs/` to `mymodule/` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39716231/4571656).**

Then in the `build.gradle` file, change:
`compile file('libs/externalDep.jar')`
to
`provided file('externalDep.jar')`

*That's it.*
It won't be copied into the aar and clients using the aar must provide the jar file themselves.
App projects using the aar can specify `compile file('lib/externalDep')` as normal.